# Assign a hexadecimal address directly to a pointer in LKM code but get different result

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I wrote the following code:

```c
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/syscalls.h>
#include <linux/version.h>

void **sys_call_table;

int __init kaslr_init(void)
{
#if KERNEL_VERSION(2, 6, 32) == LINUX_VERSION_CODE  // on CentOS 6
    sys_call_table = (void *) 0xffffffff816004c0;
#elif KERNEL_VERSION(4, 19, 0) == LINUX_VERSION_CODE  // on Arch Linux
    sys_call_table = (void *) 0xffffffff81c001c0;
#elif KERNEL_VERSION(3, 10, 0) == LINUX_VERSION_CODE  // on CentOS 7
    sys_call_table = (void *) 0xffffffff97c03300;
#endif

    pr_err("%p\n", sys_call_table);

#if KERNEL_VERSION(4, 19, 0) != LINUX_VERSION_CODE
    if (sys_call_table[__NR_close] == sys_close)
        pr_err("Bingo!\n");
#endif
    return 0;
}

void __exit kaslr_exit(void)
{
pr_err("Bye\n");
}

module_init(kaslr_init);
module_exit(kaslr_exit);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

And get the results:

```
// on CentOS 6
ffffffff816004c0
Bingo!

// on CentOS 7
[ 1375.358780] ffffffff97c03300
[ 1375.361958] Bingo!

// on Arch Linux
[ 1185.136873] 00000000bd3b9e65
```

From the result, I got a user-space address on Arch.

First I thought it maybe the reason of `kaslr`, so I disabled it by adding `nokaslr` parameter in `/etc/default/grub` and rebooted. But it still remained.

Is there any kernel security mechanism which leads to such the result?

## Heading

Comment: In my opinion, this question should be also tagged with `printk` because of [`pr_err`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/printk.h#L295) is no more than one of wrappers for `printk`. `%p` here is `printk` format specifier.

Answer (score 1):

On Arch Linux (newer kernel) kernel pointer scrambling enabled by default. Use `%px` format.

See [Pointer Types](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/printk-formats.txt) in `printk` formats for details ([`pr_err`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5.6/source/include/linux/printk.h#L303) is just wrapper around `printk`)